# Desktop Internet Explorer won't open in Windows 8 on Microsoft Surface Pro 3

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop, internet-explorer-11

I have a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 running windows 8.1. Internet Explorer works in the touch mode but even though the desktop mode is running, I can't navigate to it. It shows as an icon on the taskbar and the small preview screen shows up when I hover on the icon but IE Desktop won't open when I click on it.